# Character table of direct group product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory

Consider a finite group $G$ and assume it decomposes as

$$G\cong\displaystyle\bigoplus_{k=1}^n G_k.$$

Say that I know the character table for all of $G_k$. Can I construct the character table for $G$?

We consider complex irreducible representations, i.e. group homomorphisms $\pi : G\to\operatorname{End}(\mathbb C^n).$

In particular, the case $n=2$ is of interest, since I have a situation like this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes. The complex irreducible representations of $G_1\times G_2$ are tensor products $(V_1\otimes V_2,\rho_1\otimes\rho_2)$ of complex irreducible representations $(V_1,\rho_1)$ of $G_1$ and $(V_2,\rho_2)$ of $G_2$. The character associated to a tensor product is just a product of characters, $\chi_{\small V_1\otimes V_2}(g_1,g_2)=\chi_{V_1}(g_1)\chi_{V_2}(g_2)$. The conjugacy classes of a direct product $G_1\times G_2$ are Cartesian products $K_1\times K_2$ of conjugacy classes $K_1$ of $G_1$ and $K_2$ of $G_2$. Therefore, the character table of $G_1\times G_2$ is just the "Kronecker product" of the tables for the groups $G_1$ and $G_2$ (viewing the tables as matrices).

Comment: I thought this only held when you wanted representations of the tensor product of the spaces $V_1$ and $V_2$

Comment: @MarkusKlyver What does the word "this" in your sentence refer to? The tensor products of irreps give all irreps of a direct product, which is what you wanted.

Comment: Consider my case. I have $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z \oplus S_3$. The cyclic group of order 2 has 2 irreducible representations and $S_3$ has 3. Despite this, their product, the symmetries of a regular hexagon, only has 5 irreducible representations. What's wrong here?

Comment: Your statement that $C_2\times S_3$ has only 5 irreps must be wrong. Its 6 irreps are the tensor product of the 2 from $C_2$ and the 3 from $S_3$. I expect most (mathematical) textbooks covering complex representations of finite groups state and prove this fact about irreps of direct products.

Comment: The claim is taken directly from MathWold.  http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DihedralGroupD6.html

Comment: @MarkusKlyver That article clearly shows there are 6 irreps, indexed 0-5. :-)